# About lucene searcher optimizer~

Tags: optimization, lucene

i use lucene3.6 version to design a Searcher.But it is too slow to search my index.I want to know how can i optimize my searcher program. Thank you ~

Comment: Apart from the version number, this is similar to the question I suggested as duplicate. Please read the answers to that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ImproveSearchingSpeed